# Queue data in DB (MYSQL) based on time

Tags: c, database, linux

What is the best way to retrieve data based on the time they entered the DB?

for example, the following saved in a DB

```
data 1 saved now 
data 2 saved now+1
data 3 saved now+2
data 4 saved now+3
data 5 saved now+4
```

Then what is the best way to get data 1, data 2 then 3, like a fifo

and the other question is let's say data data 3 failed to be processed then what is the best way to save it again with new time value so it will be processed after 4 and before 5, so it will be like so,

```
data 4 saved 
data 3 saved 
data 5 saved
```

I was thinking with straight forward solution which is get the rows with sorting the date and try to process them one by one then get another set of row, but I don't think that is sufficient as I need to select the whole table and sort it then process it, I Imagine if I have millions of rows then that will be really bad.

And is it possible to use something else other than DB to do this for the described above? and please keep in mind that I need the data to be saved on a disk in case the server restarted.

The environment I'm working on is Linux and C with multiple threads/processes

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to execute complex queries on the data then you can implement a fifo queue backed by secondary drive. You don't even need to store timestamp because queue order implies a timestamp order. You can keep chunks of, say 1000 rows, in separate files and keep the least recent rows in the main memory. In this scenario, a database may not be necessary.

Comment: I was going to write something about adding timestamps to the rows, but for this problem I think you're right that a queue is the way to go.